# onClick fade in list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So this is what I'm trying to achieve:

1) 
When the mobile nav button is clicked - open the main nav and add a class of 'active' to the main nav, and a class of 'dark-header' to the header.

2) 
Check if the main nav has a class of 'active', if it does then loop through each of the list items in the main nav and fade them in one by one. (Preferably from the top left but I haven't figured out how to do that yet)

The code I have works at the minute to a certain extent but the nav items do not fade in so there is something not quite right. It does this instead: when the mobile nav button is clicked the menu opens, a class of 'active' is added to the main nav and also a class of dark header is added to the header but I just can't seem to get the main nav items to fade in from top left on after the other, instead they just appear onClick.

Here is the HTML code I have so far:

```
<!-- site header -->
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-20 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-50">
            <a class="site-logo" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="site-logo"></a>
        </div>
        <nav id="main-nav" class="grid-70 tablet-grid-100 mobile-grid-100">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="float-right grid-10 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-50">
            <a id="mobnav-btn" class="mobnav-btn">
                <span class="mobnav-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header><!-- end site header -->
```

Here is the jQuery code I have so far (Sorry if it's a mess, I just started learning jQuery):

```
$('#mobnav-btn').click(function(){
    $('.main-nav').toggleClass("active");
    $(this).parents('.site-header').toggleClass('dark-header');
        if ( $('.main-nav').hasClass(".active") ) {
                $('.main-nav li').each(function(index, element) {
                $(element).delay(index*50).fadeIn(400);
            });
        };
});
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong on this one or any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you styled your `<li>` elements as `display:none`?

Comment: Or alternatively `$(element).hide().delay(index*50).fadeIn(400);`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I tried both the above, display:none and the jQuery you provided but to no avail. I have created a very basic JSFiddle though the link is here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2bP8c/)

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
$(element).delay(index*50).fadeIn(400);
```

To

```
$(element).children('a').delay(index*50).hide().fadeIn(400);
```

Refer [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bP8c/1/) (note timings changed for testing)

Comment: Ok so now they're fading in but from the right. Is there any way to have them fade in from above where they would normally sit if the menu was in its expanded state? Also each time I click the nav menu button the menu items fade in slower and slower each time the menu is opened and closed.

Comment: Just checked the update fiddle and I cant notice any change in the timings of the fade in when I repeatedly click the 'click' button so not sure what you mean. Sorry but its late - will check again tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

There is minor mistake in your code. You need to replace

```
if ( $('.main-nav').hasClass(".active") )
```

with

```
if ( $('.main-nav').hasClass("active") )
```

"." is not nedded in hasClass method

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. I removed the period but the menu still appears straight away without the loop fading the list items in. Maybe its a problem with the order of the code? Any other ideas?

Comment: can you try to make a jsfiddle. It will be easier to debug your code then

Comment: Yes, i'll make one now.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

`$('.main-nav').hasClass(".active")`

it should be `$('.main-nav').hasClass("active")`

"." should not be there while checking for a class.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. I removed the period but the menu still appears straight away without the loop fading the list items in. Maybe its a problem with the order of the code? Any other ideas?